# Encrypt and Decrypt files using Node.js Crypto Stream

Tags: node.js, encryption, electron, filestream

I am making a Desktop application using Electron and react.js in which I have to encrypt and decrypt files (.txt, .pdf, .jpg, .png) using Crypto library.
I am using streams to do that.
So I just get the file from FileAPI and pass the file path to create readStream.

```
export function encrypt (passphrase) {
 const crypto = require('crypto');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes192', passphrase);
 const input = fs.createReadStream(file_path);
 const output = fs.createWriteStream('test.enc');
 input.pipe(cipher).pipe(output);}

export function decrypt (passphrase) {
 const crypto = require('crypto');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const cipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes192', passphrase);
 const input = fs.createReadStream(file_path);
 const output = fs.createWriteStream('test.pdf');}
 input.pipe(cipher).pipe(output);
```

This code works fine for only for .txt files.

Any help to make this work for other file formats?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

so here is a function that works.. just call on the function using 'data' in which ever format you need.. it seems best using strings or buffers.

```
function Encrypt_AES(data, pubkey) {

const algorithm = 'aes-192-cbc';
// Use the async `crypto.scrypt()` instead.
const key = crypto.scryptSync(pubkey, 'salt', 24);
// Use `crypto.randomBytes` to generate a random iv instead of the static iv
// shown here.
const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0); // Initialization vector.

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);

let encrypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'hex');
encrypted += cipher.final('hex');

return encrypted;

}

function Decrypt_AES(data, pubkey) {
const algorithm = 'aes-192-cbc';
// Use the async `crypto.scrypt()` instead.
const key = crypto.scryptSync(pubkey, 'salt', 24);
// The IV is usually passed along with the ciphertext.
const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0); // Initialization vector.

const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);

// Encrypted using same algorithm, key and iv.

let decrypted = decipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf8');
decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');


return decrypted;
}
```